# vs code - JavaScript error occurred in the main process

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just installed VS Code a few minutes ago and for some strange reason it won't open.It just throws me an error. I have no idea what it means so please take a look.

[image]

Comment: If the question is still actual for someone, it is likely that this will help: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13474

Comment: Here is the solution, https://360techexplorer.com/a-javascript-error-occurred-in-the-main-process/

Answer (score 7):

Some file got missed at the time of upgrading/ accidentally. So repair/reinstall should work. I repaired and started working fine.

Comment: Reinstallation is worked for me. Thanks